# Unable to create a div inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an `iframe` and I want to add a `div` to it using JavaScript. But it's not showing up. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
  <body>

      <iframe
        id="zzz"
        srcdoc="<html><h1>hello</h1><button>click </button> <button>btn 2</button></html>"
        width="500"
        height="500">
      </iframe>

    <script>
      let myiframe = document.getElementById("zzz").contentWindow.document;
      let mydiv = myiframe.createElement("div");
      mydiv.style.background = "red";
      mydiv.style.width = "300px";

      myiframe.body.appendChild(mydiv);
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I'm running this on my local server using VSCode live server extension and I also ran it on w3schools tryit editor too:

[image]

See, no red div here!

**Edit 1:**

Okay, I checked the DOM too. Still nothing here...

[image]

Comment: The `<div>` has a zero height, so it won’t be visible. The code works fine. How are you making sure whether or not the `<div>` is inserted?

Comment: I've added a style too to add a height. It's still not working! @SebastianSimon

Comment: [Edit] the post and create a [mre]. Describe where exactly this code runs. Locally (`file:` protocol) or a server? Which server? HTTPS or not? An IDE? Which one? Where in the IDE are you executing the code? Etc. It works fine for me.

Comment: just did that @SebastianSimon

Comment: Not `width`, `height`! Look at the DOM by using your dev tools and you’ll find a `<div>` there.

Comment: Works if you use the load event https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ju8t6xoq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome likes a load event - also we can use document.getElementById("zzz").contentDocument;

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ju8t6xoq/

Stacksnippets will not allow accessing the iFrame

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  let myiframeDocument = document.getElementById("zzz").contentDocument;
  let mydiv = myiframeDocument.createElement("div");
  mydiv.style.background = "red";
  mydiv.style.width = "300px";
  mydiv.style.height = "300px";
  mydiv.textContent = 'bla'

  myiframeDocument.body.appendChild(mydiv);
});
```